# What should i do when meteor encounters iron:router error when i deployed?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwvD1.jpg)

The home page of the site encounters "Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "

When i go to http://banjadev.meteor.com/databases it's detecting but it's not showing my navigation n footer which i included in main.html

Comment: So what's the issue? Did you route on `/`?

Comment: of course i did.i know it's the code problem but it's working fine on localhost.without run--production it works fine..what should i do?.i wonder how some links work.Like this-  http://banjadev.meteor.com/courses

Comment: Please show your router code. You need to have a route defined for `/`

Comment: I think the problem is i used 4 router files for routing process in that some came multiple times..is this can be a problem?

Comment: Here- https://github.com/leoharsha/testbanja

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your [mcve].